# Pygame installed but Pycharm cannot find the module

Tags: python, macos, module, pip, pygame

Installed pygame through Terminal using pip3 (v.10.0.1) Checked the version, the output: Requirement already satisfied: pygame in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (1.9.6)

Pycharm however does not find the module and returns:
File "/Users/dildora/PycharmProjects/GameOfLife_/venv/file1.py", line 1, in 
    import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

I tried to change the file location for pygame, but I can't even find it in the Finder.

Using macOS High Sierra.

Answer (score 1):

You installed the package in another python environment. Thus you can either use this specific environment or install the package to your IDE environment.

I suggest you to install it into the IDE one so you don't have to configure that much. PyCharm even offers a gui based installation option ([PyCharm install packages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html)).